# Understanding SAW filter from optical image

Tags: filter

As i know ladder type filters comprised by series and parallel resonator arrays. I suppose dark blue areas are series and light blue areas are parallel arrays(or opposite) in the below figure. I wonder if this structure contains reflector. Also i wonder which parts series and which parts parallel if i think right. Is there anyone who has worked on this before can help me to understand this structure?
This structure is a 1575MHz filter.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hint: your computer has a "screenshot" functionality, so that you don't need to photograph your screen. The image quality will be waaaaay better. If your microscope plugs in directly into your screen, it might also offer a way to insert e.g. a storage medium to take screenshots, or to connect to a PC.

Comment: It would be easier if you told us how the pads that these bonding wires go to were labeled.

Comment: I showed IN and OUT pads of the IC. Other pins are ground. Also IN and OUT can change place in itself, i couldn't remember exactly. But IN and OUT are pins in the middle.

Comment: Given the tight geometry sub-wavelength for epoxy or polyamide substrates, the impedance transformations with dielectric SAW resonators will give the unique band reject, bandpass shape properties. Falstad ALSO does any transmission line  properties,, but not yet any models for dielectric resonators. GND paths for in and out are on the right, other traces ?  FDX bandsplit filter?

Comment: Yes, there are 4GND pads. Other 4 pins are ground. And this is a Band pass filter.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say the dark blue are the series piezoelectric structures while the light blue ones are the shunt to GND, as you suggested. Too bad we can’t see the intedigits structures - maybe if you scratch the blue parts?

Comment: @joribama Does this type filters need recleftors before IN/OUT? Or are there 3 series and 3 shunt filters on this filter?

Comment: As an answer to my question: Every resonator consist of reclector and IDT electrodes. So the structure is more obvious now. I attached a schematic which shows the reflectors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to my question: Every resonator consist of reclector and IDT electrodes. So the structure is more obvious now. I attached a schematic which shows the reflectors too